# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, tuples, strip

I want to receive the text australia and trim all the extra characters. I am trying to achive this using strip, but getting an error

```
result = [('australia',)]
result = result[0].strip('(')
```

```
  File "./prog.py", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

What is the right way to achieve the same. Thank you.

Comment: `result[0]` is a tuple, because `result` is a list with one tuple in it. `result[0][0]` is the string. So, do `result[0][0].strip('(')` instead. Also, I'm voting to close this for being a typo.

Comment: There are no parentheses in your list, just like there are no brackets or quotation marks.  You have a list containing a 1-item tuple which contains a string.

Comment: There is no `(` to strip; the OP is confusing the tuple representation with a string. It's a simple mistake, but it's far from merely a typo.

Comment: @RandomDavis it was not a typo but my understanding of tuple was incorrect. Thank you for the description, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `(` is not part of a string value; you have a 1-element tuple as the first list item, and you need to *index* it: `result = result[0][0]`.

```
>>> result = [('australia',)]
>>> result[0]
('australia',)
>>> result[0][0]
'australia'
```